# Play radio link in iOS 6 app

Tags: ios, iphone, internet-radio

I am try to play radio in my app on Play Button. Basically I need radio streaming from a link , I am able to play mp3 files from url in AVPlayer but when i change my url with radio Streaming link its not working. My radio streaming link is 'http://usa-vn.mixstream.net:8138'
Please suggest me how to do radio streaming in my app. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/Introduction/Introduction.html) documentation?

I think, everything you need is there.